# Login problem with https

Tags: login, https

I have a wordpress site works good over than 3 years. Recently I actived https for it. After that, when I visit the dashboard, I always be redirected to login page.

I found this on Codex:

> Secure HTTPS
>
> If you are having a problem with secure HTTPS, change the following line in wp-includes/vars.php from:
>
> define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|http://[^/]+|i', '', get_settings('home') . '/' ) );
>
> To:
>
> define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_settings('home') . '/' ) );
>
> Be sure also to change the URL in OPTIONS to https://.

But I cannot find `define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|http://[^/]+|i', '', get_settings('home') . '/' ) );` in the `vars.php`. My wordpress's version is 4.7.

In the `functions.php`, I use this action to prevent users visit the dashboard:

```
add_action('init', 'IUI_prevent_backend');
function IUI_prevent_backend() {
  global $pagenow;

  if($pagenow == 'wp-login.php') {

    $page = home_url('/login');

  } elseif (is_admin() && !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) && !current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('edit_events')) {

    $page = home_url('/login');
  }

  wp_redirect($page);
}
```

I tried to remove this action and nothing changes. I don't think it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the codex on [**Administration Over SSL**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) and also shouldn't edit the core wordpress files as it isn't advised and your edits get overwritten on update.

You should define **FORCE_SSL_ADMIN** in your **wp-config.php**

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Comment: I did. It doesn't help.

Comment: Does the main site work as it should over https? and are you using a reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes. The main site works fine. I am using Nginx.